# Setting cell size with span (ajaxcrud.com)

Tags: html, css-tables

I'm using ajaxcrud.com and there's a function that allow me to format my field. It do so by including a `<span>` just before my text. Something like:

```
<table>
<td><span>Text here</span></td>
</table>
```

My problem is that my cells width are all the same. So if I have a lot of text in a cell, it only make a cell with a huge height.

Is there anyway I can use this `<span>` to expand my cell width?

Comment: You can change the display of the span and increase its width

Comment: `display: block` or `display: inline-block`; either will probably work fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the `display` of the `<span>` element to either `block` or `inline-block`.  Then you can set a `width` rule for the span that the table cell will respect.  You can set this to a specific pixel width, a percentage, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution suggested by Explosion Pills:

```
<table>
<td><span style='display:block; width:400px;'>Text here</span></td>
</table>
```

Of course, you can adjust the width to your needs.